# websraping from Skytrax website with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Can anyone review this code below fro web scrapping from skytrax website and also I am unsure how I am meant to convert the star ratings into numeric representation based on rating value. any tips would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link = "https://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/emirates/page/1/sortby=post_date%3ADesc&pagesize=100"

page = read_html(link)

pax_name= page %>% html_nodes(".grippy-host , .userStatusWrapper") %>% html_text()

date = page %>% html_nodes("time , .grippy-host") %>% html_text()

pax_rating = page %>% html_nodes(".grippy-host , .rating-10") %>% html_text()

traveller_type = page %>% html_nodes(".type_of_traveller+ .review-value") %>% html_text()

trip_verified = page %>% html_nodes("em , .grippy-host") %>% html_text()

crew_service = page %>% html_nodes(".grippy-host , .cabin_staff_service+ .stars") %>% html_text()

pax_recommended = page %>% html_nodes("t.recommended+ .review-value") %>% html_text()

food_drinks = page %>% html_nodes(".food_and_beverages+ .stars") %>% html_text()

ground_service = page %>% html_nodes(".ground_service+ .stars") %>% html_text()

travel_class= page %>% html_nodes(".cabin_flown+ .review-value") %>% html_text()

emirates_reviews = data.frame(pax_name, date, pax_rating, traveller_type, trip_verified,
      crew_service, pax_recommended, food_drinks, ground_service, travel_class, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Your link appears to direct to a 404

Answer (score 0):

On this page there's not an html element for a rating. Instead there are html elements for each individual start and the class of the star is either "star" or "star fill".

[image: stars]

So it seems like the only way to find the rating is to count the number of filled in stars for each row in the ratings table. Here's an example of how to do that for the first review table . You'll still have to figure out a way to keep this information attached to the rest of the review, but here's a way to get just the ratings bit of each review:

```
# define target url
url <- "https://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/emirates/?sortby=post_date%3ADesc&pagesize=100"

page_html <- url %>% read_html() 


# Find all the reviews
reviews <- page_html  %>% html_nodes(".review-ratings")

# find each invidual star's class
stars <- reviews[1] %>% html_nodes(".review-rating-stars.stars") %>% html_children() %>% html_attr("class")

# create a dataframe where each row is a review category and each column is a star's class
stars_df <- matrix(stars, nrow = length(stars)/5) %>% as.data.frame()

# count the number of filled in stars and make it a new column
stars_df$rating <- apply(stars_df, 1, function(x) length(which(x=="star fill")))

# pull the review ratings table for this review
review_table <- reviews[1] %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]
         
# count the number of filled in stars and make it a new column
review_table$rating <- apply(stars_df, 1, function(x) length(which(x=="star fill")))
```

Here's the result

```
> review_table
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  X1                        X2 rating
  <chr>                  <int>  <int>
1 Food & Beverages       12345      5
2 Inflight Entertainment 12345      5
3 Seat Comfort           12345      5
4 Staff Service          12345      1
5 Value for Money        12345      0
```